# How to make array search case in sensitive in this search

Tags: jquery

I am searching an array this way .

```
var requested_data_one = 'One';
var T1Data = [];
T1Data = {'ONE','TWO','THREE'};
var t1conatins = ifContains(T1Data,requested_data_one);
alert(t1conatins);

function ifContains(arr,obj) {
return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}
```

This works fine ,could you please tell me how to make this search case insensitive ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have everything in caps, you could use `String.toUpperCase()`

```
function ifContains(arr, obj) {
   return (arr.indexOf(obj.toUpperCase()) != -1);
}
```

So, everything will be transformed into CAPS and will be checked. BTW the first and second line can be combined so the final code:

```
var T1Data = ['ONE','TWO','THREE'];
alert(ifContains(T1Data,'One'));
```

Comment: Only glad to have helped you! @PreethiJain